# Security exception crash

Tags: android, runtime-error, android-permissions

My android app is using firebase and requires access to the internet, therefore in my manifest I put the internet permission, however logcat seems to think otherwise.

Here is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="com.powerofpixels.chipin"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:name=".Chipin"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".ui.activities.BirthdayActivity">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.activities.AuthenticateActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is the error message:

> Process: com.powerofpixels.chipin, PID: 4044
>                                                                           java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET
>   permission?)
>                                                                               at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:451)
>                                                                               at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
>                                                                               at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
>                                                                               at java.net.Socket.tryAllAddresses(Socket.java:109)
>                                                                               at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:178)
>                                                                               at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:150)
>                                                                               at javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket.(SSLSocket.java:764)
>                                                                               at
>   com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:186)
>                                                                               at
>   com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(OpenSSLSocketFactoryImpl.java:68)
>                                                                               at com.firebase.tubesock.WebSocket.createSocket(WebSocket.java:317)
>                                                                               at com.firebase.tubesock.WebSocket.run(WebSocket.java:117)
>                                                                            Caused by: android.system.GaiException: android_getaddrinfo failed:
>   EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
>                                                                               at libcore.io.Posix.android_getaddrinfo(Native Method)
>                                                                               at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:55)
>                                                                               at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:438)
>                                                                               at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252) 
>                                                                               at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215) 
>                                                                               at java.net.Socket.tryAllAddresses(Socket.java:109) 
>                                                                               at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:178) 
>                                                                               at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:150) 
>                                                                               at javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket.(SSLSocket.java:764) 
>                                                                               at
>   com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:186) 
>                                                                               at
>   com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(OpenSSLSocketFactoryImpl.java:68) 
>                                                                               at com.firebase.tubesock.WebSocket.createSocket(WebSocket.java:317) 
>                                                                               at com.firebase.tubesock.WebSocket.run(WebSocket.java:117) 
>                                                                            Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: android_getaddrinfo failed:
>   EACCES (Permission denied)
>                                                                               at libcore.io.Posix.android_getaddrinfo(Native Method) 
>                                                                               at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:55) 
>                                                                               at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:438) 
>                                                                               at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252) 
>                                                                               at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215) 
>                                                                               at java.net.Socket.tryAllAddresses(Socket.java:109) 
>                                                                               at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:178) 
>                                                                               at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:150) 
>                                                                               at javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket.(SSLSocket.java:764) 
>                                                                               at
>   com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:186) 
>                                                                               at
>   com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(OpenSSLSocketFactoryImpl.java:68) 
>                                                                               at com.firebase.tubesock.WebSocket.createSocket(WebSocket.java:317) 
>                                                                               at com.firebase.tubesock.WebSocket.run(WebSocket.java:117)

Why is it crashing? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `uses-permission` and not `permission` element in your manifest.

Answer (score 2):

oh! you have a small typo in there!

Change

```
<permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

to

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Dangit. So close. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's "uses-permission" not "permission". Replace your permissions line with the following line

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```